# SVG elements rendering in browser but not visible on screen

Tags: angular, svg

I'm using `DomSanitizer` and `SafeHtml` to inject `svg` code into my component.  I can see in the console that all the elements are rendering, but they're not visible on my screen.  I'm using the `DomSanitizer` because I'm generating the code from a data object.  Here's an example of an element generated by the code

```
<svg:polyline id="left_arm_line_10" points="67.379982,339.7200012 72.1800003,562.5199585 61.2800064,592.4199829 75.0799942,614.3199463 76.2800064,715.4199829 81.2800064,756.4199829 85.2800064,712.5199585 84.879982,603.5199585 74.7800064,587.5199585 85.6800003,558.2199707 85.379982,347.519989" stroke="black" stroke-width=".22" fill="none" />
```

When pasting it directly between `<svg></svg>` tags it becomes visible on the screen.  I'm rendering my `svg.component` in this fashion.

```
<svg:g svg-component [Data]="SvgData"></svg:g>
```

I made a stackblitz demo which you can [view here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pttyfi) and I noticed inside this demo that the `graphic.component` renders but not the `svg` inside the template.  Other than that all the data clearly makes it to where it needs to be seeing that I can copy and paste the outputted svg elements, I really can't figure out what's going wrong here. prior to this point I was using a `<text>` element in the `svg.component` template for the *component works* text which rendered fine so I really don't understand what's so different now.

Comment: Presumably they are in the wrong namespace.

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Comment: ok I read that document and so far I'm applying everything the way it suggests.  can you point specifically to something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe DomSanitizer and SafeHtml simply don't support non-HTML namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with your svg. [stackblitz with working svg in template url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-load-svg?file=src/app/app.component.svg)

A simple svg like the following works like a charm.

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

The problem with your svg is your viewbox which is way off and that's why your svg is not visible.

Check in the stackblitz the 1000 1000 viewbox (zoom out) and you will see that your svg is both rendered and shown. Just not where you expect it to be. It's way off down the page and you need a much higher viewport to make it visible.

Comment: yes I noticed when I placed the element directly into the SVG tag it does show up.  I'm trying to figure out why the one iterated into the `graphic.component` isn't rendering.  I need that one to work because I have my actual code set up to iterate each element into a component.  I tinkered with the `viewBox` to see if it was showing up way somewhere else like you mentioned but it just wasn't visible at all until I put it directly into the `<svg>`tags.

Comment: can you show me a demo with it visible?  I expanded the viewport a great deal and even added a fill to the overall element just to see if I see the edge of a rectangle somewhere, I didn't see anything.  yet if I hardcorde the element into the `graphic.component`'s template it renders withing the space defined, so why does that show up within view while the one I'm injecting into the template is way off to one side somewhere where  I can't find it?

Comment: How about this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-load-svg?file=src/app/app.component.svg it includes your own svg inside it.

Comment: ok maybe I should've been clearer with what I'm doing in my question.  In the stackblitz you'll see that I have a `graphic-component` folder with a component inside of it.  I'm distinctly trying to get my demo object to render through that because I built a mechanism that iterates the elements into that component.  You keep showing it to me hardcoded directly into the `<svg>` tag when there should be a `<g graphic-component />` in there.

Comment: I generate the element code from a data store of properties to get the resulting element that I'm trying to inject into the `graphic.componet`'s template with the `[innerHtml]` and `DomSanitizer`.  It shows up in the console, but doesn't display on the screen